# Getting the id of a table row and passing it to a event handler when a checkbox is checked

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

This question was posted almost eight years ago, (Question 16853364).  When I follow the answer that was provided the code runs but the the value of the record Id is not past to the event handler.  I'm using ASP.NET Core 3.1 creating a Razor Page application.  I assume the original question was based on using ASP.NET 2.x and MVC,  Hopefully that is why it is not working for me.

The Index page is a list to task that a user has been assigned.  I've added a checkbox to the page; after completing the user checks the checkbox. Checking the box should trigger an event handler that will update a column (tinyInt) in the database.  Checking the checkbox does call the event handler, however the code that should get the record's Id before call the handler does not get the Id.  My code on the Index.cshtml that displays the records and calls the handler is:

```
...
@if (Model.ScheduleOut.Count() == 0)
        {
            <p>
                This speaker has not been scheduled in the past six weeks or in the next 6 months...
            </p>
        }
        else
        {
        <table class="table table-striped border" height="40">
            <tr class="table-secondary">
                <th>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SchedOutgoingVM.ScheduleOutObj, "Id:")
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SchedOutgoingVM.ScheduleOutObj, "DOT:")
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SchedOutgoingVM.ScheduleOutObj, "Talk #'s:")
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.SchedOutgoingVM.CongObj.CongName)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SchedOutgoingVM, "Date / Time:")
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SchedOutgoingVM, "Talk Coordinator:")
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SchedOutgoingVM, "TC's Phone:")
                </th>

                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>


            <!-- *************** display records ***************-->
            @foreach (var item in Model.ScheduleOut)
            {
            <tr id="1">
                <td class="tdBorder">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Id)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.DOT)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.SpkTalkNum)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Congregation.CongName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Congregation.MtgDay) / @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Congregation.MtgTime)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Congregation.tcFirstName) @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Congregation.tcLastName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Congregation.tcMobilePhone)
                </td>

                <td>
                    <!-- check or uncheck checkbox based on value in database -->
                    @if (item.Accepted == null || item.Accepted == 0)
                    {
                        <!-- if false in the database-->
                        <input asp-for="AcceptedBoolean" type="checkbox" onclick="ckBox(this)" form-check-input">
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <!-- if true in the database-->
                        <input asp-for="AcceptedBoolean" type="checkbox" checked="checked" onclick="ckBox(this)" form-check-input">
                    }
                </td>

            </tr>
            }
        </table>
        }

...
```

**The Index.cshtml.cs**

```
    ...
 

//********** OnPost - update Accepted (tinyInt)column in database (using id) **********
        public async Task<JsonResult> OnGetUpDateAccepted(int id)
        {
            ///code to update database
                        
            return new JsonResult(id);
        }
    ...
```

Any suggestion on what I'm doing wrong or missing is greatly appreciated.  If you have a better way of updating the database I would like to know that also.

**Javascript Code:**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
    function ckBox(e) {
        if (e.checked) {

            ////var Testt = $(this).closest('tr').attr('Testtid');
            ////alert('Got this far...')

            var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
            console.log(Testt);    //used to capture the value at this point
            alert(id);

            $.getJSON('?handler=UpDateAccepted&Testt=' + id, (data) => {
                
            });
        } else {
            var Testt = 0
            alert('bye');

            $.getJSON('?handler=UpDateAccepted&Testt=' + id, (data) => {
                
            });

        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: js code added to the bottom of the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly,you comment on some js code when you debug the code,and this caused the js in a mess.The variable name is not correct in your sample.Be careful with theses variables.

Then,the backend paramater named id,so the request url should be:`'?handler=UpDateAccepted&id=' + id` instead of
`'?handler=UpDateAccepted&Testt=' + id`.

Finally,you want to pass the id of the record,but all of the tr have the same id.You need change `<tr id="1">` to:`<tr id="@item.Id">`.

Here is my whole working demo:

Model:

```
public class ScheduleOut
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DOT { get; set; }
    public string SpkTalkNum { get; set; }
    public int? Accepted { get; set; }
    public Congregation Congregation { get; set; }
}
public class Congregation
{
    public string CongName { get; set; }
    public string MtgTime { get; set; }
    public string tcFirstName { get; set; }
    public string tcLastName { get; set; }
    public string tcMobilePhone { get; set; }
    public int MtgDay { get; set; }
}
public class SchedOutgoingVM
{
    public ScheduleOut ScheduleOutObj { get; set; }
    public Congregation CongObj { get; set; }
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@if (Model.ScheduleOut.Count() == 0)
{
    <p>
        This speaker has not been scheduled in the past six weeks or in the next 6 months...
    </p>
}
else
{
<table class="table table-striped border" height="40">
    <tr class="table-secondary">
        <th>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SchedOutgoingVM.ScheduleOutObj, "Id:")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SchedOutgoingVM.ScheduleOutObj, "DOT:")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SchedOutgoingVM.ScheduleOutObj, "Talk #'s:")
        </th>
        //...
        <th>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SchedOutgoingVM, "TC's Phone:")
        </th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.ScheduleOut)
    {
        <!-- *************** change here ***************-->
        <tr id="@item.Id">
            <td class="tdBorder">
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.DOT)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.SpkTalkNum)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Congregation.CongName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Congregation.MtgDay) / @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Congregation.MtgTime)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Congregation.tcFirstName) @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Congregation.tcLastName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Congregation.tcMobilePhone)
            </td>

            <td>
                @if (item.Accepted == null || item.Accepted == 0)
                {
                    <input asp-for="AcceptedBoolean" type="checkbox" onclick="ckBox(this)" form-check-input">
                }
                else
                {
                    <input asp-for="AcceptedBoolean" type="checkbox" checked="checked" onclick="ckBox(this)" form-check-input">
                }
            </td>

        </tr>
    }
</table>
}
```

JS in Index.cshtml:

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">  
    function ckBox(e) {
        if (e.checked) {
            var id = $(e).closest('tr').attr('id');
            $.getJSON('?handler=UpDateAccepted&id=' + id, (data) => {
                
            });
        } else {
            //do your stuff...

        }
    }
    </script>
}
```

Result:

[image]

BTW,if User unchecked the checkbox,it seems also need to get the id to update.If what I guess is correct,you need change like below:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">  
    function ckBox(e) {
        var id = $(e).closest('tr').attr('id');
        $.getJSON('?handler=UpDateAccepted&id=' + id, (data) => {
            
        });  
    }
</script>
```